# How to produce assemble effect in software product videos

Tags: animation

I have seen in different software product videos that the UI is assembling during the video. How is such an effect produced?

Here are a couple of examples:

Lumiar:

Salesforce:

How are these sequences produced? Which tools are getting used?

Answer (score 1):

These sequences are produced using Animation™. Animation™ is the technique of manipulating objects or images to create the appearance of motion. If you look closely at the sequences, maybe slowing them down so you can step through them frame by frame you'll be able to see what's going on, and then you just have to work out how to do it with whatever tools you use.

I'd say screen shots of the UI elements have been chopped up with an image editor (e.g. , CinePaint, Darktable, DigiKam, F-Spot, G'MIC, GIMP, GimPhoto, GIMPshop, GNU Paint, GrafX2, GraphicsMagick, gThumb, Hugin, ImageJ, ImageMagick, Inkscape, KolourPaint, Krita, LazPaint, LightZone, MyPaint, Panorama Tools, Pencil2D, Phatch, Pinta, Rawstudio, RawTherapee, Seashore, Shotwell, Tile Studio, Tux Paint, UFRaw, XPaint, Brush Strokes Image Editor, Chasys Draw IES, FastStone Image Viewer, Fatpaint, Fire Alpaca, Fotografix, IrfanView, MediBang Paint Pro, Moai[1], Paint.NET, PhotoScape, PixBuilder Photo Editor, Pixia, Project Dogwaffle 1.2 Free Version, XnView, Ability Photopaint, ACD Canvas X (formerly Deneba Canvas), ACDSee, Acorn Image Editor, Adobe Photoshop, Adobe Photoshop Lightroom, Adobe Photoshop Elements, Affinity Photo, ArcSoft PhotoImpression, Artipic, ArtRage, Autodesk SketchBook Pro, Bloom Image Editor, Capture One, CodedColor PhotoStudio Pro, Corel Painter, Corel Painter Essentials, Corel PaintShop Pro, Corel Photo-Paint, Erdas Imagine, GraphicConverter, Helicon Filter, Iridient Developer, LView Pro, Manga Studio, Microsoft Paint, NeoPaint, OpenCanvas, Paint Tool SAI, Photogenics, PhotoLine, Photo Mechanic, Photos (Apple app), Photo Raster, PicMaster, Pixelmator, Pixen, PMview, Portrait Professional, Project Dogwaffle, QFX, Serif PhotoPlus, TVPaint, Xara Photo & Graphic Designer, Zoner Photo Studio, Mara, Pixlr, PicMonkey, PicsArt).

Then the separate elements were then moved around in an animation / compositing app, e.g. Blender, Cinelerra, Kdenlive, Natron, OpenShot, Shotcut, Adobe After Effects, Apple Motion, Autodesk 3ds Max, Autodesk Inferno, Flame and Flint, Autodesk Maya, Autodesk Smoke, CompTime, FXhome HitFilm, Saber, Houdini, Blackmagic Fusion, Mistika, Nuke, Piranha, SilhouetteFX, Autodesk Combustion, Autodesk Softimage, Autodesk Toxik, Aviary, Peacock, Avid DS, Avid Elastic Reality, Avid Matador, Avid Media Illusion, Kodak Cineon, FXhome Lab, Range, Pinnacle Commotion, Silicon Grail's RAYZ and Chalice or Shake.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's just an animation video composed with several (SEVERAL; see below) layers of objects moving around in a scripted way. Probably they took a screenshot or a screen recording of those programs, disassembled them through an editing program, and then assembled them back again with the same editing program, scripting all the movements.

In the first case I guess such a video is exported at a ridicolously high definition, and is then re-edited after exportation, so that it can be moved around, tilted...

In the second video I think they attached it on the screens of the various devices using After Effects.

I specified "several" because I once did something like that, with a composing interface, for an interactive Youtube video, this one

I made it with Premiere. That menu at the beginning of the video, alone, and the way it assembles, required around 20 layers. They were quite simple, since they included only shapes with different opacities, colours and movements; yet it was impossible for my usual PC, a laptop with which I'm even able to export 4K movies, to process all those layers. I had to go to a friend's house and use his semi-pro PC made for this kind of jobs.

It's possible, though, that there are programs, such as the ones mentioned above, that can make such an animation easier compared to Premiere.